# R: distHaversine function not delivering expected results

Tags: r, geosphere

I am using `distHaversine` function to find the distance between the Vatican and a list of German cities.

`mutate(kita_fees_df, distance = distHaversine(cbind(Longitude, Latitude), cbind(40.5409, 12.2709)))`

```
regional_schlÃ.ssel city_kreis  Latitude    Longitude   distance
01002                  Kiel     10.13727    54.321775   2183273
```

When I use a distance calculator I find that the distance should be around 1540 kilometers. Am I using this function properly?1

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem.  `distHaversine(cbind(54.321775, 10.13727), cbind(40.5409, 12.2709))/1000` returns 1523 km.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful! I'm going to take another look at my data.

Comment: Also check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110815/how-to-use-disthaversine-function

Comment: I solved the problem: strings were being imported as factors.